# Ionic 3 Firebase can't access redirect result data

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

I am working on a Ionic 3 app and I am having a small issue with the `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` function. It looks like it does not access the `then` function. I tried to console log the result, but it does not appear in console, neither does a random console log of a `string`. Am I doing something wrong there?

Here is the code:

```
signInWithGoogle() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

    return firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
    .then(() => {
        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data); // Does not print this
            console.log('User signed in.'); // Neither this
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            throw (error);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        throw (error);
    });
}
```

It logs nothing in console, but it passes the auth. It successfully logs in the account.

Comment: Are you sure.You haven't got any error?

Comment: @NakulKundaliya If there is one error I really don't see it, also the log is empty...

Comment: Note that it works if I am using the sign in with popup method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code.

import Google plus dependency.

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
```

Add following code in you login function

```
this.googlePlus.login({
  'webClientId': ' ' // Your Google console id
}).then((success) => {
  console.log("===login with googlePlus==",success)
  Let credential = free-base. Auth. GoogleAuthProvider. credential (success ['idToken'], null);
  firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
    .then((success) => {
      console.log("=====success",success)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("=====error",error)
      let code = error["code"];
    });
}, error => {  });
```

i hope it work for you.